# Why does the Mutex instance let the controller to work properly well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, mutex

Here is a part of a controller (I deal with ASP.net Web Api 2 ). When the controller receives a request from the client's side it starts and activates a Mutex instance. In `catch` block I release the mutex instance (ReleaseMutex method) but in the `try` block I have forgotten to do this trick and it works, it performs like the have been released before?
Just why?

```
namespace HMMM
{
    public class MYSTERYController : ApiController
    {
        public Mutex Mutec = new Mutex();
        public JObject MYSTERY([FromBody] string  SomeStuff)
        {
            Mutec.WaitOne();//attention
            try
            {
                //blablabla 
                //not released Mutex                  
                return Error.json("TheSameBlaBlaBla");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Mutec.ReleaseMutex();//Attention
                return Error.json("SomeCoolError");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of advice. Release `Mutex` in `finally` block and not in `catch`. This will ensure your `Mutex` will be released irrespective of exception or happy scenario.